# Toggle Display of Only Nearest Element in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, aurelia

I could easily do this with vanilla JS or jQuery but wondering what the "correct" way to simply achieve the following is in Aurelia.

I have a ton of "cards" with toggle buttons to show that cards "hidden-info".  With the way that I'm currently doing it, clicking any "expand-toggle" display all cards "hidden-info".

What is the right way to toggle only the nearest sibling with Aurelia?

Here's my `example.html`:

```
<div class="inner">
    <i class="expand-toggle" click.delegate="expandCard()"></i>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div if.bind="cardExpanded" class="au-animate hidden-info">
    </div>
</div>
```

And my `example.js`:

```
export class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.cardExpanded = false;
    }

    expandCard() {
        this.cardExpanded = true;
    }
}
```

Also, how would I then hide it on the next click. This is basic but I am new to Aurelia. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post any CSS you have for .hidden-info? It's not clear if your div is being rendered onLoad.

Comment: Hey Nick, the .hidden-info does not have any css controlling its display...you can see that it is hidden onLoad with the if.bind="cardExpanded" property.

Comment: Ok then I think you can just change the line `this.cardExpanded = true;` to `this.cardExpanded = !this.cardExpanded;` and that should be a basic toggle.

Comment: Hey Nick.  Thanks that definitely works to toggle the elements but it does not solve my main issue of one toggle toggling all instances of hidden-info.

Comment: What does your parent component look like? What you have here should work as expected as there should be a separate instance of your `Example` class for every card. Each instance of your card should know about it's own `cardExpanded` state. Unless you have some other jquery floating around also trying to expand these cards?

Comment: Thanks, @dpix. This is the parent component.  But the cards all exist in the same template so they are all getting the cardExpanded state.

Comment: Ok, what you want to do instead is create a component that just handles the state for an individual card. Then you can use a repeater to create one of those components for every card. Sorry I don't have time to write up a proper answer right now but can do later. Check out http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-custom-elements/1 and http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-basics/9

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  This makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

I would try

example.html:

```
<div class="inner">
    <i class="expand-toggle" click.delegate="expandCard(this)"></i>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div if.bind="cardExpanded" class="au-animate hidden-info">
    </div>
</div>
```

example.js:

```
export class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.cardExpanded = false;
    }

    expandCard(sender) {
        sender.cardExpanded = !sender.cardExpanded;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also try `click.delegate="expandCard($this)`